# How to make a plugin like app in iphone

Tags: iphone

I want to make an plugin like app in iphone for mobile web browser, in which i want to use safari (or any browser) current link and also link which is present on the web page, when i click on it my app should invoke for using targeted link.

I know plugins are not supported in mobile browser,

Can anybody have any solution without jailbreak?

Thanks in advance.